Ansible custome module in different roles can't share the same names
I have an ansible project where I have two separte roles roleA and roleB both of them have custom module called test.sh.
Whenever I use the two roles one after the in a playbook both are executing the test.sh that was first included. Why is that and how can I force each role to use its own script.
Here is my folder structure
root
|--/roles
|----/roleA
|------/library
|--------/test.sh
|------/tasks
|--------/main.yml
|----/roleB
|------/library
|--------/test.sh
|------/tasks
|--------/main.yml
|--/site.yml

Here is the main.yml for RoleA
- name: Test RoleA
  test: {}

- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts['msg'] }}"
  

Here is the test.sh for RoleA
#!/bin/bash

echo "{\"changed\": \"true\", \"ansible_facts\":{\"msg\":\"ROLE-A\"}}"

Here is the site.yml
- name: "Test RoleA"
  hosts: builders
  roles:
    - role: roleA

- name: "Test RoleB"
  hosts: builders
  roles:
    - role: roleB

As far as I understand the normal behaviour should be that each role will take its own test.sh however this is not my case and I have no idea why
Last here is the output
PLAY [Test RoleA] *************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform darwin on host mac-farm-7125 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python3, but future installation of another
Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.17/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html
for more information.
ok: [mac-farm-7125]

TASK [roleB : Test RoleA] ************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [mac-farm-7125]

TASK [roleB : debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [mac-farm-7125] => {
    "msg": "ROLE-A"
}

PLAY [Test RoleB] *****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [mac-farm-7125]

TASK [roleA : Test RoleB] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [mac-farm-7125]

TASK [roleA : debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [mac-farm-7125] => {
    "msg": "ROLE-A"
}

At the end I should expect that the msg in ansible fact should be Role-A right after TestRoleA playbook was executed and Role-B after TestRoleB was executed
PLease help me, this is driving me nuts ;( ;(

Any there hints in documentation Adding modules and plugins locally?

Would this "role-scope custom modules" work your you?

@U880D Unfortunately no. The documentation is stating that To use a standalone module only in a single role, store the module in a subdirectory called library within that role.. However that is exactly what I am doing and to the best of my understanding it doesn't behave like in the docs

I've found out there are two issues open with ansible for this but nothing has been done:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/68694
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/36028

